# Modal not showing in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, web-deployment

So I have an issue, I have made a map application with various features in vanilla js. I am now trying to translate all this code to vue.js and it's a slow process. I have a modal I want to popup when clicking the button "Add step", but it doesn't. I have read documentation and viewed examples but I can't figure it out.

As I mentioned I've tried various examples I've found here on stackoverflow and elsewhere.

I understand the solution might be very simple indeed, but I'm stuck and this modal wont show. Any tips or tricks? Things to think about when using vue?
Here is a fiddle of my entire project in it's wholesome, https://jsfiddle.net/8Lmjrhgs/ .
Many thanks for your time people!

This is how my vanilla.js modal looked like

````
let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: data() { return { ...

```
data()  {
return {
showModal: false,
    isEditing: false,
    user: {
        mapTitle: 'Add a title to your map',
        mapDescription: 'Add a description to your map',
    },
    steps: [{title: "", description: ""}],
    step: {title: "", description: ""}
}

},
```

Don't put your v-show on the transition-group, put it on the immediate child, the same actually goes for click, I would also not toggle the value for "Close modal", since you dont for "Open modal" at least id make those handle that the same way.

```
<transition name="modal" :modalData='customData' @close='showModal = !showModal'>
        <div class="modal-mask" v-show="showModal">
```

I believe the main issue here was the way you've created the component, which in this specific case is redundant since all the code is there anyway (but your real code might be actually importing it, so I cant say for sure)
Removing your script tags got the modal out.

https://jsfiddle.net/1kv24wyr/1/

Comment: Expert or not you solved it. Thanks! Yeah I am not sure why the script tags caused it though. On vue.js example page which I got it from they use it and it works fine there (obviously). As I said thank you!

Comment: Glad to could be of help mate.

Comment: Would appreciate if you marked it as the answer SebHolst ;)